# how to return all substrings on the page using xpath

Tags: xpath

This xpath returns the number and positioning that I want

```
substring(.//*[@class="book-title-wrapper"]/h3/a/@href, 8)
```

How do I return all substrings on the page?

Comment: What do you mean by all substrings from page? Substrings from which strings?

Comment: so to search this 

substring(.//*[@class="book-title-wrapper"]/h3/a/@href, 8)

everywhere it will come up

Comment: It currently only comes up with 1 result and there are 50 on the page to find

Comment: .//*[@class='book-title-wrapper']/h3/a/@href 

will return

/book/-9780399590504

I just want the long number from that

Comment: no way with xpath 1.0

Comment: How are you executing the XPath? You can't achieve what you want with just XPath 1.0, but that doesn't mean you can't achieve it. If we knew what you were using, we could suggest a solution for selecting of of the `@href` using XPath and then iterating over them and selecting the substring for each.